# Bootstrap "class=text-center" vs. CSS "text-align: center"

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

We may possibly stop using the Bootstrap framework, so I want to know if replacing `class="text-center"` with vanilla CSS will change anything. Is there any difference in behavior between

```
<!--Bootstrap files already included-->
<header>
    <p class="text-center">Some text</p>
</header>
```

and

```
<header>
    <p>Some text</p>
</header>

...

/*Separate style.css file*/
header p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

?

Comment: Do you want all of the paragraphs in the page centered? Read more on CSS selectors.

Comment: No, that was just a dummy selector.

Comment: If there is a difference between using the Bootstrap class versus the CSS attribute.

Comment: Bootstrap _is using css_ to do this.  The class is a utility class to allow you to easily add that behavior to any elements you want.  So - there's actually no practical difference between the two options you are asking other than stripping classes.  Are you completely moving away from Bootstrap? If so, you're going to have to roll your own CSS for a bunch of things...

Comment: bootstrap is a css library

Comment: @Zim No they don't "produce different results". Maybe you didn't understand the OP's question. The Bootstrap source code has `.text-center {  text-align: center !important; }`, so there's no difference between the two.

Comment: The OP's question is essentially whether Bootstrap does *anything extra* to elements with the class `.text-center`, **in addition to** `text-align: center;`, the answer to which is no.

Comment: @xji Read the entire question. Of course I know what Bootstrap `text-center` does. That's not the question. The question is using the style inline on one specific `<p>` vs. setting it on all paragraphs. It you look at the edit history of the question you'll see that it originally said `p {text-align:center}` which would center *all* `<p>` on the entire page, not just one that's the difference I mentioned *before* the question was edited to use `header p` as the CSS selector.

Comment: @Zim Right. My wordings might have been unjust as I only get to see the edited version of the question. The OP used an example that is not entirely accurate for his intended question. Doesn't mean he intended to ask what his example falsely conveyed. He also agrees by accepting my answer.

Comment: My original example was misleading which is why I edited it, which unfortunately can appear to invalidate some of the existing answers and comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP's question seems to have been edited after it was first posted. It essentially asks: whether Bootstrap does *anything extra* to elements with the class `.text-center`, **in addition to** `text-align: center;`. I also had this doubt and the answer is no. I think this question can be better answered by just looking at Bootstrap's source code:

```
.text-center {
  text-align: center !important; }
```

Apparently all that Bootstrap does is to apply one CSS rule: `text-align: center !important;` to such an element. So yeah they can be considered equivalent.

Comment: "A lot of commentators and even the accepted answer apparently didn't understand the OP's question". The question was edited from when it was originally posted. Originally the question had a CSS selector that applied to all paragraphs. Not just the one inside the header. That's why the original answer is more relevant to the original question.

Comment: @Zim Right. My wordings might have been unjust as I only get to see the edited version of the question. The OP used an example that is not entirely accurate for his intended question. Doesn't mean he intended to ask what his example falsely conveyed. He also agrees by accepting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just keep in mind that the `p` selector will apply that style to *every* `<p>` tag in your page. If this is a style you definitely want every `<p>` to have, then you can use it. If you only want *some* of them to have this style, then stick with the class. Sidenote, you can use the following syntax to target only elements that are `<p class="text-center">` without affecting other tags with the same class.

```
p.text-center {
    text-align:center
}
```

**NOTE:** To clarify something, this is basic CCS functionality, completely independent of bootstrap. You could do this whether you are using it or not.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, there is no added value from a behavioral aspect of your code or functionality so I will not tackle that aspect of the question, however, I believe that this is a matter of making your code easily understood by other developers.

Simply finding a 'text-center' class justifies behavior that's happening to the tag element without the need to dig into the CSS class to understand it, and making the access to modify that class more convenient for other developers on task (developer already having the HTML page open on his text editor VS using devTools to find out the relevant class and/or CSS file causing the undesired effect, navigating onto that file and applying the necessary functions), and I believe it makes for a better semantic code.